# Python save matplotlib figure on an PIL Image object

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

HI, is it possible that I created a image from matplotlib and I save it on an image object I created from PIL? Sounds very hard? Who can help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To render Matplotlib images in a webpage in the Django Framework:

- create the matplotlib plot
- save it as a png file
- store this image in a string buffer (using PIL)
- pass this buffer to Django's ***HttpResponse*** (set *mime type* image/png)
- which returns a *response object* (the rendered plot in this case).

In other words, all of these steps should be placed in a Django *view* function, in ***views.py***:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT
import numpy as NP
import StringIO
import PIL
from django.http import HttpResponse 


def display_image(request) :
    # next 5 lines just create a matplotlib plot
    t = NP.arange(-1., 1., 100)
    s = NP.sin(NP.pi * x)
    fig = PLT.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.plot(t, s, 'b.')

    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    canvas = PLT.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
    canvas.draw()
    pil_image = PIL.Image.frombytes(
        'RGB', canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.tostring_rgb())
    pil_image.save(buffer, 'PNG')
    PLT.close()
    # Django's HttpResponse reads the buffer and extracts the image
    return HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')
```

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same question and I stumbled upon this answer. Just wanted to add to the above answer that `PIL.Image.fromstring` has been deprecated and frombytes should be used now instead of fromstring. Hence, we should modify line:

```
pil_image = PIL.Image.fromstring('RGB', canvas.get_width_height(), 
                 canvas.tostring_rgb())
```

to

```
pil_image = PIL.Image.frombytes('RGB', canvas.get_width_height(), 
                 canvas.tostring_rgb())
```