# Simple plotting library that returns PIL-format images?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to plot x-y graphs and I want to annotate certain points on the graph.

I am displaying it in a UI panel, so the output must be a PIL-format image.

What is a good lightweight plotting library for Python that returns PIL-format images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html) is powerful, and can save `.png`'s, but it needs numpy.

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4302192/624900) for how to save directly to PIL image